# Can I do a Bash wildcard expansion (*) on an entire pipeline of commands?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am using Linux. I have a directory of many files, I want to use `grep`, `tail` and wildcard expansion `*` in tandem to print the last occurrence of <pattern> in each file:

```
Input: <some command>
Expected Output: 
<last occurrence of pattern in file 1>
<last occurrence of pattern in file 2>
...
<last occurrence of pattern in file N>
```

What I am trying now is `grep "pattern" * | tail -n 1` but the output contains only one line, which is the last occurrence of pattern in the last file. I assume the reason is because the `*` wildcard expansion happens before pipelining of commands, so the `tail` runs only once.

Does there exist some Bash syntax so that I can achieve the expected outcome, i.e. let `tail` run for each file?

- I know I can always use a for-loop to solve the problem. I'm just curious if the problem can be solved with a more condensed command.

---

I've also tried `grep -m1 "pattern" <(tac *)`, and it seems like the aforementioned reasoning still applies: wildcard expansion applies to only to the immediate command it is associated with, and the "outer" command runs only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards are expanded on the command line before any command runs. For example if you have files `foo` and `bar` in your directory and run `grep pattern * | tail -n1` then bash transforms this into `grep pattern foo bar | tail -n1` and runs that. Since there's only one stream of output from grep, there's only one stream of input to tail and it prints the last line of that stream.

If you want to search each file and print the last line of grep's output separately you can use a loop:

```
for file in * ; do
  grep pattern "${file}" | tail -n1
done
```

The problem with non-loop solutions is that `tail` doesn't inherently know where the output of one file ends and the output of another file begins, or indeed that there are even files involved on the other end of the pipe. It just knows input is coming in from somewhere and it has to print the last line of that input. If you didn't want a loop, you'd have to use a more powerful tool like `awk` and perhaps use the fact that grep prepends the names of matched files (if multiple files are matched, or with `-H`) to delimit the start and end of outputs from each file. But, the work to write an `awk` program that keeps track of the current file to know when its output ends and print its last line is probably more effort than is worth when the loop solution is so simple.

Comment: You're completely right about using a loop being appropriate, but it's probably better to replace the `grep | tail` pattern inside that loop with the OP's `tac | grep -m 1`; that way they're reading backwards from the end of each file and stopping at the first match, instead of needing to read the entire file from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html). For your example it would be:

```
ls * | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'grep "pattern" $0 | tail -n 1'
```

Can save you from having to write a loop.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In particular, this will mishandle filenames with spaces, quotes, backslashes because of xargs doing its own unescaping and string splitting _in addition to_ problems caused by `ls` trying to format output for humans should there be any names with nonprintable characters.

Comment: A more reliable alternative is `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg; do grep "pattern" "$arg" | tail -n 1; done' sh` -- also more efficient because we don't start a separate copy of `sh` per file. (The second `sh` is a placeholder for `$0` so the default for loop target of `"$@"` has our filenames). `xargs -0` is an extension, but while it's not POSIX-mandated, both BSD and GNU worlds have implemented it for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. Interesting link. Wasn't aware of that. Can see myself still using `ls` though just for convenience and out of habit given the unlikely-ness of it going wrong. That being said it's good to be aware of this. Thanks.

Comment: Unlikely things can do a lot of damage when they _do_ happen. Granted, this was a once-in-a-career event, but I've seen a company's backups of records used to support customer billing wiped out by a shell script that assumed the names would be safe to expand unquoted; files were only created by internally-written code that named them with hex digits. Until one day there was a buffer overflow and random memory got dumped into a filename; that random content contained a whitespace-surrounded `*`. It's worth cultivating good habits so you're writing safe code when it turns out to matter.

Comment: I was thinking if Bash had some sort of "anonymous lambda" expressions as one would encounter in C++, that can make a one-line solution to my problem possible. `xargs` seems to be that equivalent! Thanks DzedCPT. Also many thanks to Charles for providing a more robust and efficient solution, although yours uses a `for` loop, I indeed learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk`, although (as tjm3772 pointed out in their answer) it's actually more complicated than the shell `for` loop. For the record, here's what I came up with:

```
awk -v pattern="YourPatternHere" '(FNR==1 && line!="") {print line; line=""}; $0~pattern {line=$0}; END {if (line!="") print line}'
```

Explanation: when it finds a matching line (`$0~pattern`), it stores that line in the `line` variable (`{line=$0}`) (this means that at the end of the file, `line` will hold the last matching line.

(Note: if you want to just include a literal pattern in the program, remove the `-v pattern="YourPatternHere"` part and replace `$0~pattern` with just `/YourPatternHere/`)

There's no simple trigger to print a match at the end of each file, so that part's split into two pieces: if it's the first line of a file AND `line` is set because of a match in the previous file (`(FNR==1 && line!="")`), print `line` and then clear it so it's not mistaken for a match in the current file (`{print line; line=""}`). Finally, at the end of the final file (`END`), print a match found in that last file if there was one (`{if (line!="") print line}`).

Also, note that the print-at-beginning-of-new-file test *must* be before the check for a matching line, or else it'll get very confused if the first line of the new file matches.

So... yeah, a shell `for` loop is simpler (and much easier to get right).